# Personal account appears in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have used the free month trial offered by Azure with a personal Microsoft account in parallel with a professional account from my company. In this professional account I have limited access to certain resources (mostly VMs, storage and that), so I don't manage neither subscriptions nor Azure AD.

After several unsuccessfull login attemps in which I was asked to provided a 6 digit code when the Microsoft Authenticator gave me an 8 digit code, I've discovered that if I do the following:

1. Try to sign in in azure.portal.com with my personal account (fails)
2. Sign in with my company account.

Then, in the upper right I see my personal account as a directory, like **usenamehotmail.onmicrosoft.com**. However, when trying to access Azure AD to manage that directory I am shown a message that says I have no access.

My question is, why does this happen? Can I use the same credit card and create a pay as you go subscription with another personal Microsoft account?

Comment: for login attempt failures which account are you using and what are you trying to achieve.  can you be more clear on the issue. so that we can help you further

Comment: Hello, I am using my personal account, username@hotmail.com. I also have access to Azure via my company account, but that account gives me no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you using the external account to access Azure AD like outlook.com, hotmail.com and the account from other Azure AD tenant. it will cause the Access Denied(you don't have access).

There are two ways to resolve this issue

```
  1. Log in to Azure Portal by using the account with Global Administrator Role for Azure AD. Navigate to the User settings tab, toggle the setting Guest users permissions are limited to No.

  2. Log in to Azure Portal by using the account with Global Administrator Role and navigate to the Users and Groups tab, search for the external account, and change the Directory Role to Global Administrator.
```